# undefined constant problem with xampp

Tags: php

i have two problems with xamp

first problem

My code

```
if($_REQUEST['foo']){
    echo 'bar';
}
```

error: Notice: Undefined index: foo in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_file.php on line 5

second problem

My code

```
define( THEME ,'theme/');
```

Error: Notice: Use of undefined constant THEME - assumed 'THEME'

How i can solve this problems ?

problem solved:
i was think the problem is in xampp because files was working fine on apache but sorry that's was my maistake , thank you all

Comment: The problem here is that you're using a constant to define a constant. Put " around your constant name like Artefacto pointed out and it will work. General PHP error by the way, has nothing to do with xampp ;-)

Comment: that is not problem with xamp - only php knowledge

Comment: Thank you bjorn kaiser problem solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (key_exists('foo', $_REQUEST) && $_REQUEST['foo']){
...
}
```

Access to array keys that don't exist emit a notice (except for special constructs like `isset` or `empty`; incidentally, you could rewrite your condition as `if (!empty($_REQUEST['foo']))`, since `empty` is aligned with whether a value would be converted to `FALSE` if coerced to a boolean), so you should check for them first.

```
define( "THEME" ,'theme/');
```

`define` takes a string as a first parameter, just `THEME` looks like a constant, so PHP looks for one; not finding one it reverts to the string `"THEME"`, which is what you want. But it's a string you want, you should give it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['foo'])){
    echo 'bar';
}
```

Second:

```
define('THEME', 'theme/');
```

Answer (score 0):

please, read this about using $_REQUEST: http://devlog.info/2010/02/04/why-php-request-array-is-dangerous/

$_REQUEST contains everything from $_POST, $_GET and $_COOKIE. If there is nog $_POST['foo'], $_GET['foo'] or $_COOKIE['foo'], then $_REQUEST['foo'] don't exists.

Second:

if you want to define something, always use "" or '', like for example:

```
define( "THEME" , "/theme/goes/here/" );
```

Comment: That's not very accurate; by default `$_REQUEST` contains everything from those sources, but that's configurable.

Comment: i was think the problem is in xampp because files was working fine on apache but sorry that's was my maistake , thank you all